# When do you use "apply" and when "funcall"?

Tags: common-lisp

The *Common Lisp HyperSpec* says in the `funcall` entry that

```
(funcall function arg1 arg2 ...) 
==  (apply function arg1 arg2 ... nil) 
==  (apply function (list arg1 arg2 ...))
```

Since they are somehow equivalent, when would you use `apply`, and when `funcall`?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You should use `funcall` if you have one or more separate arguments and `apply` if you have your arguments in a list

```
(defun passargs (&rest args) (apply #'myfun args))
```

or

```
(defun passargs (a b) (funcall #'myfun a b))
```

Answer (score 12):

`apply` is useful when the argument list is known only at runtime, especially when the arguments are read dynamically as a list. You can still use `funcall` here but you have to unpack the individual arguments from the list, which is inconvenient. You can also use `apply` like `funcall` by passing in the individual arguments. The only thing it requires is that the last argument must be a list:

```
> (funcall #'+ 1 2)
3
> (apply #'+ 1 2 ())
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I think a good rule of thumb would be: use apply when you can't use funcall: the latter is clearer but is also less general than apply in that it doesn't allow you to call a function whose number of arguments is only known at runtime.

Of course it is only good practice and you *could* systematically do this the ugly way (systematically using apply), but as you've probably noticed, using the ugly way when a very similar but cleaner way is available is not very common-lisp-y.

Example of function that needs apply instead of funcall:
could you implement map in such a way that `(map #'+ '(1 2) '(2 3))` and `(map #'+ '(1 2) '(2 3) '(3 4))` both work (which is the case with the standard function) without using apply (or eval, which is cheating)?

**EDIT**: as has also been pointed out, it would be silly to write:`(funcall func (first list) (second list) (third list) etc.)` instead of `(apply func list)`.

Answer (score -2):

Apply function is curring the result, like it returns a function that applies to next argument, to next argument.
It is important subject on functional programming languages.

```
(mapcar 'list '((1 2)(3 4)))
(((1 2)) ((3 4)))

(funcall 'mapcar 'list '((1 2)(3 4)))
(((1 2)) ((3 4)))

(apply 'mapcar 'list '((1 2)(3 4)))
((1 3) (2 4))
```